# Duel Boot Ubuntu 20:04 and Windows 10 - Activation of Network Connection Failed

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet

I accidentally unplugged my desktop while it was running Ubuntu 20.04. It is a Dell XPS-8700 with duel-boot Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10. When I plugged the computer back in and turned it on I got "Activation of Network Connection Failed". I had internet through WiFi but not through Ethernet. I tried several "fixes" with no successful results. Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this 1 munute [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGdlDR2FC_A) on YouTube. I didn't think changing the power button setting in Windows 10 would work but I was desperate enough to try it. It worked for me.

I'm not sure what the Windows power button setting has to do with the Ubuntu 20.04 OS ethernet connection. At the end the video says to reinstall the Ubuntu OS - I didn't have to reinstall Ubuntu. It works just as it did before the power disruption.